# How can I use Unique_ptrs with an class object having std::function as argument in the constructor

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

**Problem Description**

We have `2` classes `A` and `B`. `B` has the following constructor:

```
B(std::function<std::unique_ptr<A>()> a)
```

I am trying to create a `unique_ptr` as in `std::unique_ptr<B> aPtr = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B(std::function<std::unique_ptr<A>()));` I can't figure out how to do it. It's not compiling and I can't really explain the error.

How Can I create unique_ptr for class `B`?

---

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
    A(){}
};

class B 
{
public:

    B(std::function<std::unique_ptr<A>()> a):_a(std::move(a)) {}

private:
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<A>()> _a;
};

int main() {
    //std::unique_ptr<B> bPtr = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B(std::function<std::unique_ptr<A>()));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `<` has no closing `>`. Also, what function do you want `_a` to store? Should it just be empty?

Comment: You need a `A` factory (`std::function<std::unique_ptr<A>()>`) as `[](){ return std::make_unique<A>(); }`

Comment: @Jarod42 I updated the code can you check it please? you are the only guy that made the right comment

Comment: Don't use `new`.  Do this instead: `unique_ptr<B> bPtr = make_unique<B>([]{ return make_unique<A>(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto bPtr = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B( std::function< std::unique_ptr<A>() > () ));
//                                     need to close the template         ^
//                                     need to construct an instance of     ^^
```

You get the same a bit simpler by using `std::make_unique`:

```
auto bPtr = std::make_unique<B>( std::function< std::unique_ptr<A>() >() );
//                                               still as above      ^^^
```

Edit: Adjustment to new question version:

You have not yet provided a copy constructor – so you need to store the lambda instead of creating a `B` instance:

```
auto l = []() { return std::make_unique<A>(); };
auto bPtr = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B(l));
// or:
auto ptr  = std::make_unique<B>(l);
```

Note that this new edited version provides a factory function to the `std::function` object (the lambda!), while the initial variants constructed an empty one without function stored inside, so not callable!

Answer (score 2):

You might construct a B by passing a `std::function` (or value which might convert to).

For example appropriate lambda:

```
B b{[]() { return std::make_unique<A>(); }};
```

If you really want `std::unique_ptr<B>`, then it becomes:

```
std::unique_ptr<B> b = std::make_unique<B>([]() { return std::make_unique<A>(); });
```

Comment: thank you Jarod. Really appreciate it. Thanks a lot man